# Docker Compose extra_hosts from env_file and not from default .env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using version 2 of docker-compose files.

Is it possible to read extra_hosts from env_file?

I have already defined common variables for all docker-compose in one environment variable file.

Sample :-

```
version: '2'
workspace:
  env_file:
    - "../shared_environment/shared_variables.env"
  extra_hosts:
    - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
    - "windowshost:${WINDOWS_HOST_IP}"
```

When I run docker-compose config it has following output.

```
workspace:
environment:
  DOCKER_HOST_IP: 192.168.99.100
  WINDOWS_HOST_IP: 192.168.99.1
extra_hosts:
- 'dockerhost:'
- 'windowshost:'
```

So in above output I am able to see that it is reading file but after that how can I use it inside extra_hosts?

Comment: just call the `DOCKER_HOST_IP` inside you container or `DOCKER_HOST_IP:PORT` to access another container inside container

Comment: Hello @Adiii I am new bie in docker can you please post sample. I tried to use it but it has error message like following. invalid IP address in add-host: "DOCKER_HOST_IP"

Answer (score 2):

The `env_file` configuration passes environment variables from an external file to the service's container. See [The “env_file” configuration option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option).

The `extra_hosts` in your `docker-compose.yml` file uses [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).

> Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which
>   docker-compose is run.

To configure the IPs for the `extra_hosts`, you can set the values in a [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) file or export them (e.g. `export DOCKER_HOST_IP=192.168.99.100`) in the shell running `docker-compose`.

> You can set default values for environment variables using a .env file.
>   Values set in the shell environment override those set in the .env
>   file.

Content of `.env` file:

```
DOCKER_HOST_IP=192.168.99.100
WINDOWS_HOST_IP=192.168.99.1
```

Comment: So basically we can not use env_file for variable substitution. https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/634

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable substitution from `.env` for `extra_hosts`. It works properly.

**Steps:**

1. create a `.env` file with your IP
2. use the variable name in your `docker-compose.yml` file

**In practice:**

1. `$ touch .env`
2. content: `EXTERNAL_HOST=1.2.3.4`
3. add the extra host definition into your `docker-compose.yml` file:

   ```
   extra_hosts:
     - "internal-host:${EXTERNAL_HOST}"
   ```

**Verification:**

1. Log into your container with `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash`
2. `cat /etc/hosts`

**Result:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
...
1.2.3.4 internal-host
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use env variables with docker-compose, you need export them first.

IMPORTANT: `env_file` allow to use env vars inside the container, not in the yaml file itself.

consider:

docker-compose.yaml

```
my_service:  
    env_file: 
     - .env
    extra_hosts:
      - ${MY_HOSTNAME}:172.20.11.10
```

.env

```
MY_HOSTNAME=dev.myapp.com
```

for the yaml file take the values you need to do:

run.sh

```
#export env from file
set -a
source .env
set +a

#run compose
docker-compose up --build
```