# Docker Compose doesn't seem to read env variables defined in env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following project directory structure:

```
myapp/
    docker/
        docker-compose.yml
    .env
    src/
        <my source code here>
    config.properties
```

Here is my `.env` file:

```
ENV=local
SERVICE_DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
SERVICE_DB_PORT=3306
SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
SERVICE_DB_APP_USER=my-service-user
SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD=23456
```

Here is my `docker/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  myapp-main-db:
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: myapp-main-db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - $SERVICE_DB_PORT:$SERVICE_DB_PORT
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp_service_db_$ENV
      MYSQL_USER: $SERVICE_DB_APP_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - myapp-service-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  myapp-service-db-data:
```

When I run `docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up -d` from the project root directory, I see the MySQL container spin up without issue, and verify its running via `docker ps`.

**However** I am unable to connect to it using the expected connection string and credentials, which I am **sure** are correct. This leads me to believe that Docker Compose is not loading the `../.env` file as I was expecting it to, and so none of the variables defined in `../.env` are being injected as env vars.

**Can anybody spot where I'm going awry?**

#### Update

When I run `docker-compose config` I get:

```
$ docker-compose config
WARNING: The SERVICE_DB_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The ENV variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The SERVICE_DB_APP_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.myapp-main-db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

Comment: I am not sure, but could it be that the path that you give to the "env_file" is relative to the current dir where you launch docker-compose from and not to the directory containing docker-compose.yml? In this case you could try by changing it to ./.env but, I repeat, I am not sure

Comment: First of all, for debugging purposes, I'd suggest you try the command [`docker-compose config`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/) to display the whole, implied configuration (with the variables substituted…)

Comment: Thanks @EuberDeveloper (+1) but when I change it to `./.env` and re-run the command I get `ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /Users/myuser/workspace/myapp-service/docker/.env`, so I do believe `../.env` is correct.

Comment: Thanks @ErikMD (+1) please see my edit above which includes the output of `docker-compose config`. So it seems my suspicions are correct, that its **not** loading the variables defined in the `../.env` file.

Comment: Taking a closer look at your docker-compose.yml, it seems the two notions `env_file` and `.env` are somewhat entangled, while there are definitely different notions! Maybe the SO thread [Docker Compose extra_hosts from env_file and not from default .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58170665/9164010) could be useful to you?

Comment: [The .env file path is as follows](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

    "Starting with +v1.28, .env file is placed at the base of the project directory;;
    For previous versions, it is placed in the current working directory where the Docker Compose command is executed unless a --project-directory is defined which overrides the path for the .env file. This inconsistency is addressed in +v1.28 by limiting the filepath to the project directory." In my last project, it helped not to locate it at all, putting the .env in the same folder as the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 7):

Compose has two separate layers of [environment file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) handling:

1. When the `docker-compose.yml` file is read in, it reads a `.env` file from the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml`, and uses that to expand `$VARIABLE` references.
2. When an individual container is launched, it reads the `env_file:` and uses that to set environment variables in the container.

Since `.env` isn't in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file, Compose won't read it before expanding variables in the file.  That leads to the container getting empty strings for the database credentials, and the error because `ports:` is malformed.

You can either move `.env` into the same directory as `docker-compose.yml`

```sh
mv .env docker
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up
```

or pass a `docker-compose --env-file` option

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-docker-compose.yml --env-file .env up
```

You don't need `env_file:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file for this particular use and can remove it.

---

To debug this further, you can `docker-compose run` a container with an alternate `command:`.  You could for example `docker-compose run myapp-main-db env` to print out its environment instead of launching a database.  The flow I'd expect you to see here is:

1. Compose reads `docker/.env` (from the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file), which is absent
2. Compose replaces variables in the file; I'd expect to see `MYSQL_USER` to be an empty string
3. Compose reads the `env_file:`; the container will have the additional environment variable `SERVICE_DB_APP_USER=my-service-user` from that file

Answer (score 3):

According to default behavior of docker, Dockerfile and docker-compose never read any file or value from parent directory. It always read from current directory or from Child directory.

so for your code  I suggest please use docker-compose file in source/root directory.

Example:

```
myapp/
    docker-compose.yml
    .env
    src/
        <my source code here>
    config.properties
```

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the official Docker docs: [Using the “--env-file” option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option).

> You can use an .env file from anywhere, using the --env-file option:
>
> By passing the file as an argument, you can store it anywhere and name
> it appropriately, for example, .env.ci, .env.dev, .env.prod. Passing
> the file path is done using the --env-file option:
>
> ```
> docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up
> ```

Obviously, you *cannot* go to a parent directory of your current directory to get the .env file when you are inside the docker-compose, thus, *not* like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  myapp-main-db:
    env_file:
      - ../.env
```

One way to use an .env file from somewhere else like here at the parent folder is to use the `--project-directory` parameter of the `docker-compose` command. According to the [official Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

> The .env file path is as follows:
>
> Starting with +v1.28, .env file is placed at the base of the project
> directory
>
> For previous versions, it is placed in the current working
> directory where the Docker Compose command is executed **unless a
> --project-directory is defined which overrides the path for the .env file. This inconsistency is addressed in +v1.28 by limiting the
> filepath to the project directory.**"

Which would mean in your case:

```
docker-compose --project-directory .. up
```

Or: you can reach any .env file on your system if you pass it as the `--env-file` parameter of the `docker-compose` command.

```
docker-compose --env-file ../.env up
```

If you use neither `--project-directory` nor `--env-file` you need to put the .env file where the docker-compose file is.